# Timer with Enabled value true does not work when using in WinFormAnimation

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make System.Windows.Forms.Timer to work after animation.

```cs
private Timer timer1 = new Timer();

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 25;
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;

    tempX = this.Location.X;
    new Animator2D(new Path2D(-300, 23, this.Location.Y, this.Location.Y, 1500, AnimationFunctions.ExponentialEaseOut))
    .Play(this, Animator2D.KnownProperties.Location, new SafeInvoker((() =>
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    })));

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

I use this method.
But it doesn't work

So I changed method like this.

```cs
private Timer timer1 = new Timer();

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 25;
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;

    tempX = this.Location.X;
    new Animator2D(new Path2D(-300, 23, this.Location.Y, this.Location.Y, 1500, AnimationFunctions.ExponentialEaseOut))
    .Play(this, Animator2D.KnownProperties.Location, new SafeInvoker((() =>
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => timer1.Enabled = true));
    })));

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

It work.

I don't know the difference between the methods.
Through the debugger, timer1's Enabled value is changed to True even when using the first method.

I wonder why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation:

This happens because method `Invoke` runs the code on the same thread context as [control's underlying thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) (which is the UI Thread in our case). Think of context as the current state of the thread and how it views memory at a specific time.

So when we don't use `Invoke` it is likely that the code runs on a different thread which also contains `timer1`. The code sets `Enabled` property to `true` there in that specific thread's context. Think of it as though you have two Timers instead of one - one in say thread `A` and another one in thread `B`.

Conclusion:

In order to avoid this mess we should always use `Invoke` when  we need to update fields or properties in our Form while working in multi-threaded environment.